# How to use where clause within window function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

```
with
  t1 as (
    select 'reb' as type, 1 as poss, 1 as ord, 'nick' as name union all
    select 'reb' as type, 1 as poss, 2 as ord, null as name union all
    select 'shot' as type, 1 as poss, 3 as ord, 'tom' as name union all
    select 'reb' as type, 1 as poss, 4 as ord, null as name union all
    select 'shot' as type, 1 as poss, 5 as ord, 'bil' as name union all
    select 'reb' as type, 2 as poss, 1 as ord, null as name union all
    select 'reb' as type, 2 as poss, 2 as ord, null as name union all
    select 'shot' as type, 2 as poss, 3 as ord, 'joe' as name union all
    select 'reb' as type, 2 as poss, 4 as ord, 'tim' as name union all
    select 'shot' as type, 2 as poss, 4 as ord, 'tim' as name 
  )

select
  first_value(name ignore nulls) over (partition by poss order by ord asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as firstname
  ,*
from t1
```

[image]

This is close to the output needed, but not exactly correct. We are using a window function to get the first name that appears in each `poss` partition, ordering by the `ord` field.

What we actually need is the first `name` field where the `type` is shot. The correct output for `firstname` would be `tom tom tom tom tom joe joe joe joe joe` as `tom` is the first name in `poss == 1`, based on the order, where the type is shot.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  first_value(if (type = 'shot', name, null) ignore nulls) over (
    partition by poss -- if (type = 'shot', poss, null)
    order by ord  asc
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
  ) as firstname
  ,*
from t1
order by poss asc, ord asc
```

This seems like a valid solution, didn't initially realize `if()` statements could be used in the window function like this.